# python program using json not running properly

Tags: python, json

I am trying to run this simple program on python:

```
import json
json.loads('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
```

But it is giving an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jsonURL.py", line 2, in <module>
    json.loads('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'loads'
```

I know the program is correct what am i missing here?

Comment: which version of Python?

Comment: Do you have a file called `json.py` in your project?

Comment: '2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:44:07) \n[GCC 4.6.3]'

Comment: @DanielRoseman No. is it required ? and where can I get it ?

Comment: OK now i have json.py and then also same error.

Comment: take a look at the current directory that your program was running and PYTHONPATH env variable, and ensure you do not have two json.py modules. you may include the output of : print dir(json) and print json.__file__ as edit on your post

Answer (score 4):

Do you have another python file called json.py in your path?
Also take a look at your json modules methods with `dir(json)`.